# Python function

Tags: python, string

Q1) How to write the function countLetter(word, letter) that takes in a word and a letter and returns the number of occurrence of that letter in the word.

Q2) Write a function removeLetter(word, letter) that takes in a word and remove all the occurrence of a particular letter from the word.

Q3) Write a function getVowels(word) that returns the vowels (‘a’, ‘e’, ‘i’, ‘o’, ‘u’) in a word as a list in sequence of appearance in the word.

Comment: Cool, so what have you done so far?

Comment: @Holger - is anybody studying now? :D

Answer (score 5):

```
countLetter = lambda word, letter:word.count(letter)
removeLetter = lambda word, letter:word.replace(letter, '')
getVowels = lambda word:[c for c in word if c in 'aeiou']
```

Comment: Alternative for `getVowels` that's a bit more similar to the other two: `lambda word:filter(lambda c:c in 'aeiou',word)`

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call anything that assigns a lambda expression to a variable Pythonic. Why not add `def`, parentheses, a newline and `return` and just make them regular functions?

Answer (score 0):

```
question 1

len(filter(lambda x: x == letter, word))
```

---

```
question 2

"".join([x for x in word if x != letter])
```

---

```
question 3

"".join([x for x in word if x in 'aeiou'])
```